# How to reuse contracts in Spring Cloud Contract?

Tags: java, spring, groovy, cdc

I've been using [Spring Cloud Contract](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/reference/html/project-features.html) for a while and it is great tool however it becomes tedious to define a lot of contracts when you have to repeat complex data structures inside the request body. Consider a contract like this:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {
    request {
        method(POST())
        url("transfer")
        headers {
            contentType(applicationJson())
        }
        body([
                target_account_id: "",
                source_account_id: "",
                amount: [
                        value: $(consumer(regex("\\d*\\.\\d+|\\d+")), producer(1234.435)),
                        currency: $(consumer(regex("[A-Z]{3}")), producer("GBP"))
                ],
        ])
    }
    response {
        status(OK())
        headers {
            contentType(applicationJson())
        }
        body([
                id: "",
                status: "",
        ])
    }
}
```

What is the best approach to make `amount` field reusable so that I could just do this instead?

```
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {
    request {
        method(POST())
        url("transfer")
        headers {
            contentType(applicationJson())
        }
        body([
                target_account_id: "",
                source_account_id: "",
                amount: amount(),
        ])
    }
    response {
        status(OK())
        headers {
            contentType(applicationJson())
        }
        body([
                id: "",
                status: "",
        ])
    }
}
```